# Deploy to Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

New to Windows Phone 7 development.

I am using Windows 7 32 bit pro
I am using VS2010.

I connect my WP7 mobile.
I can see the files in Windows Explorer.

I create a New W7 project. I select deploy to device.
I get this error:

"Zune software is not launched. Retry after making sure that Zune software is launched"

Zune is installed.
It seems to be running?

It still does not deploy.

I Google around.

All the answers are to select the Emulator instead.

I don't want the emulator. I want to use the device.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that on Google:
http://dhakshinamoorthy.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/getting-almost-started-with-windows-phone-7-1-development/

Αt some point says:

> " Now build the project, if everything goes right you will get an error. “Zune software is not launched. Retry after making sure that Zune software is launched.”, and please do so. Also make sure, you don’t have any keypad lock on your phone device. Also make sure the phone is not pin locked."

So in my opinion the problem is that your phone is locked and Zune can't access your device.

Comment: I have never develop Windows Phone applications, so this is my opinion based on what I found on Google. I hope, however, I helped :D

Comment: Also you will probably get an error like this:

"Failed to connect to device as it is developer locked. For details on developer unlock, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=195284.
Because paying $99 to test your applications is really annoying I found this:
http://www.techmesto.com/developer-unlock-windows-phone/

Comment: hi, thanks for all your comments/replies. i was obviously very tired last night because I had not plugged the USB into the PC! lol.  However, your links are good for me too!  Thanks

Comment: Oh... Perhaps that could prevent Windows from detecting your device... Hehehe
Anyway...
It's ok now? Are you able to deploy your application on your device?

Comment: HI, yes I can - ta. But you would think Microsoft would sort this out though :)

Comment: What about this "developer locked" error?
I have never develop for Windows Phone but I will begin soon...